# Probabilities Based on Combinations..

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For the sake of my own understanding I want to find out following probabilities related to combination:
Two friends win free ice cream coupon for newly opened ice cream shop.
At Ice Cream shop 5 different flavors are available (A, B, C, D, E) and both of them can chose any three flavors.  Flavor can be chosen randomly and any flavor can’t be chosen twice (without replacement). The choices of both friends are independent from each other.
So keep the above scenario in mind we need to find following probabilities:
1. What is the probability that both of them will choice same flavors (all three)?
2. What is the probability that both of them will choice at-least one same flavor?

Answer (score 1):

$\#\{\textrm{ways of both friends choosing three flavours}\} = {5 \choose 3}^2 = 10\cdot 10 = 100.$

$\#\{\textrm{ways of both friends choosing three flavours that are all the same}\} = {5 \choose 3} = 10$.

$\#\{\textrm{ways of two friends having 0 in common}\} = 0.$

So the probability in question $(1)$ is $\frac{10}{100} = \frac{1}{10}$ and the probability in question $(2)$ is $\frac{0}{100} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given the first person's choices, the second has to get that one group of three out of the possible ones, so $$P={1\over\binom{5}{3}}={1\over 10}$$ For the second one, how could they possibly pick all different flavors if they each get three, and only five are available?

Comment: Ice cream is available in five flavors and they can chose any three out of five..As i mention their choices are independent from each other.

Comment: for first one i want to know the probability for both..means can we calculate probabilities for both friends separate and then combine them by applying some law (multiplication)???? for second one, yes by select any combination they will select at-least one same flavor.but how we can calculate??? any formula or explanation???